# How to add Collection To Document Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a User collection in my Firstore database, and I want to imbed a Workout collection in each document of my User collection. I can do this on the Cloud Firestore Dashboard, but how can I do this when I create a new User document in my Flutter code?

My normal code for adding a user looks like this:

```
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
          await transaction
              .set(Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uuid_), {
            'grade': _grade,
            'name': _name,
          });
        });
```

but I want to somehow add a Workout subcollection to my newly created User document. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to create a new subcollection. Instead a collection is created automatically when you add the first document to it.

So something like:

```
transaction.set(
  Firestore.instance.
    collection('users').document(uuid_).
    collection("workouts").document("workoutid"), {
        'grade': _grade,
        'name': _name,
      });
```